# Problem with pgf-pie and \newcommand use

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I am currently using [pgf-pie](http://code.google.com/p/pgf-pie/) package and I face a problem when I write the pgf-pie content using `\newcommand` instruction. The following MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\testpie}{10/ A , 20/ B , 30/ C , 40/ D}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{pie}[
  text = inside,
  scale font,
  style = drop shadow
]
{
  \testpie
}
\end{pie}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

generates the following error

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `A' (in '10/ A , 20/ B , 30/ C , 40/D').
```

The final goal is to automatically generate the "fraction" sequence by reading a pgfplotstable.

**Edit:**

Going back to initial code I have something like that

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usepackage{xstring}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
  Year,TB,B,AB,P,NA
  2008/2009,15,38,15,0,31
  2009/2010,13,25,38,0,25
  2010/2011,17,50,8,17,8
}{\mention}

%% Feel free to improve the next lines
\newcommand{\pieplot}[1]{%
  \pgfplotstableforeachcolumnelement{Year}\of{#1}\as\cell{%
    \IfStrEq{\cell}{2008/2009}{%
      \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \x in {TB,B,AB,P,NA}{%
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{\x}\of{#1}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\val{\pgfplotsretval}
        \ifnum\val=0
        \else
        \val / \x
        \IfStrEq{\x}{NA}{}{,}
        \fi
      }
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
  \pieplot{\mention}
\end{document}
```

which generates the right "fraction" sequence but fails when I use `\pie` command even with `\mypie` command.

Comment: The command `\testpie` must be expanded before it passed as an argument.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 3):

Based on the rudimentary documentation and related to the code of `pgf-pie` the mandatory argument will be passed directly to a `foreach` construction. So you have to fully expand the argument first. Here a suggestion by providing a new command `\mypie`:

```
\newcommand\mypie[2][]{%
 \begingroup
  \edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\pie[#1]{#2}}
 \x}
```

Here the complete code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\testpie}{10/ A , 20/ B , 30/ C , 40/ D}

\newcommand\mypie[2][]{%
 \begingroup
  \edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\pie[#1]{#2}}
 \x}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\mypie{\testpie}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your code is working fine. My problem now is that the `\testpie` is more complicated and makes use of `\pgfplotstable` commands. I will try to adapt your answer to my problem.

Comment: I can not find a way to deal with `pgfplotstable` command. For example, if I add into the `\testpie` command, `\pgfmathtruncatemacro\dummy{0}` then the control sequence is undefined

Comment: @XavierGarrido: Please edit your original question and show your issue